# How to add a new line when I print a text from a textarea to a file?

Tags: java, file, jtextarea

When I print a text that is in a JTextArea  in a file it prints it in the same line . How can I add a new line in the file each time I have a new line in the  JTextArea ?
This is my code .

```
 print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    try {

                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


                        bw.write(valid.getText()  );
                        bw.close();


                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }                            
                }

                    }                                                    

            });
```

Comment: If it's writing everything on a single line, then you have a single line in the textarea. The text area might wrap the line automatically, but so can the editor used to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this function from your BufferedWriter object:

```
bw.newLine();
```

This command **isn't** the same like: `<br>` or `\n`